# What changes my default browser from Chrome back to IE10 in Windows 8?

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-8, google-chrome

I follow the steps outlined [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/make-ie-default-browser#ie=ie-11) but set Chrome instead of Internet Explorer. If I close all browser windows, Chrome and IE, the changes are reverted and IE becomes the default browser. I am the only user logged in.

Can I detect what process changes these settings?

Steps to change default browser:

1. Swipe in from the right edge of the screen, and then tap Search. (If you're using a mouse, point to the lower-right corner of the screen, move the mouse pointer up, and then click Search.)
2. Enter Default programs, and then tap or click Default Programs.
3. Tap or click Set your default programs.
4. Select Internet Explorer from the list of programs.
5. Tap or click Set this program as default, and then tap or click OK.

Edit 1: @Kamal - I disabled my McAfee HIPS and AV and something else keeps changing my default browser.

Edit 2: I used [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to track changes in `HKLM\Software\Classes\.html` and other file extensions but no events are registered. Whatever is changing my default browser does not use this mechanism.

Then I started monitoring the `Control Panel >> Default Programs >> Set Default Programs` control dialog and forced changes in default browser (from/to IE/Chrome) and captured tons of registry queries and updates, all done by `Explorer.exe`.

Answer (score 1):

Check your internet security/anti-virus program. It might be preventing the changes from sticking. You could try turning off your security software, make the changes and close out all your browser windows and see if the changes stuck. If yes, turn on your security software and try again.